# Loop or recursive sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, subquery

I have a table with numbers and dates (1 number each date and dates aren't necessarily at regular intervals). I would like to get the count of dates when a number isn't in the table.

What I have (just an example, dates and "chiffres" are more complex) :

```
date                      |   chiffre
2014-09-30                |        2
2014-09-29                |        1
2014-09-28                |        2
2014-09-27                |        2
2014-09-26                |        1
2014-09-25                |        2
2014-09-24                |        2
```

etc...

What I need for the number "1":

```
actual_number_of_real_dates_between_two_given_dates
  1
  3
```

My actual query thanks to Gordon Linoff

```
select count(n.id) as difference
from nums n inner join
     (select min(date) as d1, max(date) as d2
      from (select date from nums where chiffre=1 order by date desc limit 2) d
     ) dd
where n.date between dd.d1 and dd.d2
```

How can I test row 2 with 3? 3 with 4 etc... Not only last 2? Without "limit 2"
Should I use a loop? Or I can do it without?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find the gaps between `1`s in the table, you should start with the next "1":

```
select n.*,
       (select date
        from nums n2
        where n2.chiffre = 1 and n2.date > n.date
        order by date
        limit 1
       ) next_date
from nums n
where chiffre = 1;
```

Then use this as a subquery to get what you want:

```
select n.*,
       datediff(coalesce(next_date, now()), date) as days_between
from (select n.*,
             (select date
              from nums n2
              where n2.chiffre = 1 and n2.date > n.date
              order by date
              limit 1
             ) next_date
      from nums n
      where chiffre = 1
     ) n;
```

Comment: I tried to replace with datediff(next_date, date_tirage) as days_between  but I have an error Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: @sam12 . . . There should have been a `limit 1` in both.

Comment: yep thanks
now, I have a problem about first entry on the new table, next_date returns NULL value

select chiffre,
        (select count(id) from nums where n.next_date IS NOT NULL and (date between  n.date and n.next_date) ) as difference, next_date
        
from (select date, chiffre,
             (select date
              from nums n2
              where (n2.chiffre=1) and n2.date > n.date
              order by date limit 1
             ) next_date
      from nums n
      where chiffre=1 
     ) n

I tried is not null but not working :/
My final goal is to get min/max and avg value